# How can I supply a read-only property's value by calling a constructor?

Tags: c#, class, properties

I have a Book class with a constructor which has a title parameter:

```
public class Book
    public Book (string title)
        {
           this.Title = title;
        }
```

I need to supply a Title's (read-only property) value by calling the Book constructor. I tried the following but not sure if this is correct since as I understood read-only property should only have a getter.

```
public string Title { get; private set {} }
```

I need Help to Finalize  / correct this code block. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `set` is not auto-implemented as you have added a `{ }` (= empty statement block) instead of a `;`. This means that it is doing nothing. Change the property to `public string Title { get; private set; }` to make it work.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I see. Thank you for letting me know. Also, i would like to thank everyone else for taking time to answer my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have currently defined `Title`, it is able to be set from anywhere inside `Book`. That is to say, it is not read-only, merely private.

To make it read-only (in a similar way to the `readonly` keyword on fields) you can simply declare it like this:

```
public string Title { get; }
```

And then you can use the constructor code you currently have to initialize it:

```
public Book (string title)
{
    this.Title = title;
}
```

As Ran notes in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70517680/3181933), C# 9 has introduced the concept of the [`init` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init). The difference with `init` is that, while the property can still only be set once, it can be initialized from outside the constructor. This is useful if you want to use the object initializer pattern, for example.

Answer (score 3):

C# 9 introduces the `init` keyword which is a variation of `set`, which allows us to do it. The `init` accessor is actually a variant of the `set` accessor which can only be called during object initialization

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; init }; 
}
```

More about `init` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init

Answer (score 1):

Any read only field can be set in the constructor, where after the constructing is done the field will become immutable. In other words, you don't need to do anything fancy, the constructor will handle it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just do an `interface` with your

```
public string Title { get; }
```

and then implement this interface into your class/classes & do a simple `field` (outside the constructor, over your method):

```
public string Title => "xyz"; //(or string.Empty)
```